# Find hex value in files/folder

Tags: grep, search, hex

Is there a way to search for a hex value in files / folders?
I've tried the following:

```
grep -P "[\x01\x02\x03]"
```

but that doesn't work (there is no error, but it doesn't search for these hex values).

Answer (score 3):

To search through file and folders add `r`(recursive) option:

```
grep -Pr "[\x01\x02\x03]"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, now It scans through very many files, and it outputs very many files. Is it possible, that it doesn't look only for 0x01 0x02 0x03 in that order, but also for 0x02 0x01 0x03 and 0x02 0x03 0x01, and so on? I am looking for a 6 byte hex value, and I know that this only exists 5 times on my SD card ( I've checked this with a hex editor and searched the whole card for this hex value ).

Comment: @Manuel, of course, if you want to find a strict sequence specify it without character class `grep -Pr "\x01\x02\x03"`

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work a little better now.
But I've put a file on my SD Card where I've checked with my hex editor, that there is the hex value I am looking for, but if I use grep -Pr "\x01\x02\x03" it doesn't find anything, even if I add the file, where I know that it is inside. Is there another possibility to the files with these hex values?

Comment: @Manuel, RomanPerekhrest's answer matches your question as it is presently formulated. Please rephrase your question and add all those missing details if this answer is not what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your content isn't visible if you just use one example.

```
grep -aPr "[\x01\x02\x03]" *.txt >> matches.txt
grep -aPr "[\x01\x02\x03]" matches.txt >> contents.txt

OR best solution:

grep -aPr "[\x01\x02\x03]" --include=\*.txt --include=\*.html >> writetofile.txt
grep -aPr "[\x01\x02\x03]" writetofile.txt >> allresults.txt
```

The -a enables recursive file writing. It's something that cost me a whole week to figure out. Else you are doomed with matches on each file and no results.

You will have to run the grep second example double-up times to remove text in the first file from recursive writing.